# How Would I Create a Loop to Display the Months and Days in Each Month?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```java
public class Array {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
        int[] daysInMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
        System.out.println("There are a total of " + daysInMonth[0] + " days in the month of " + months[0] + ".");
    }

}
```

Instead of printing to the console 12 different times for each one of the months, how could I make my code more efficient and create a loop to print out each of the elements in my arrays?

Answer (score 3):

Try following:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    System.out.println("There are a total of " + daysInMonth[i] + " days in the month of " + months[i] + ".");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually had the following line in my code before: for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) but erased it thinking that I may have been wrong . If I'm understanding this code correctly, the reason why it works it because we're telling the programming to display "i" each time which is a changing variable. Because we have "i++" in our code which tells the program to use the value of "i" before increasing it and because we're telling our program to loop this code 12 times indicated by i < 12, it means our program will plug in values 0-11 which includes all the elements in our array?

Comment: Yes exactly, that is what loop does over here.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69457382/10819573) is correct and you should accept that. I have written this answer to introduce you to the `java.time` API.

```
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            Month month = Month.of(i);
            System.out.println(month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH) + " has a maximum of "
                    + month.maxLength() + " days.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
January has a maximum of 31 days.
February has a maximum of 29 days.
March has a maximum of 31 days.
...
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/38DCTe)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Map<String, Integer> and then iterate through it.

```
final Map<String, Integer> months = new HashMap<>();
months.put("January", 31);
months.put("February", 28);
...
months.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("There are a total of " + v + " days in the month of " + k + "."));
```

Comment: There are [several ways to initialize a hashmap](https://www.baeldung.com/java-initialize-hashmap); yours is just one of them.  But a hashmap is not what the OP is using, and while your answer is clever, semicolon's is much closer to what the OP is asking about.